# Executing functions in series

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-connect

Could you please explain to me, how does executing functions in series works?
I browsed throught [Connect's source code](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect), but I don't get it.

I would like to write it by myself.

```
app.get(
  '/',
  function(req, res, next) {
    // Set variable        
    req.var = 'Happy new year!';
    // Go to next function
    next();
  },
  function(req, res, next) {
    // Returns 'Happy new year!' 
    console.log(req.var); // <- HOW IS THIS POSSIBLE?
    // (...)
  }      
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though the first function argument you provide gets called by the `get()` function first.

When it is called, 3 parameters are provided to the call. Inside the call, the `req` parameter must be an object to which you can assign properties. You've assigned the `var` property, and given it a value of `'Happy new year!'`.

The next function argument you pass is called via a call to the `next()` parameter, and 3 parameters are again provided to the call. The first parameter is apparently the same object that was given to the first call where you assigned the `var` property.

Because it is (apparently) the same object, the property you assigned is still present.

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/dWfRv/1/ *(open your console)*

```
// The main get() function. It has two function parameters.
function get(fn1, fn2) {
      // create an empty object that is passed as argument to both functions.
    var obj = {};
      // create a function that is passed to the first function, 
      //   which calls the second, passing it the "obj".
    var nxt = function() {
        fn2(obj); //When the first function calls this function, it fires the second.
    };
      // Call the first function, passing the "obj" and "nxt" as arguments.
    fn1(obj, nxt);
}

// Call get(), giving it two functions as parameters
get(
  function(req, next) {
      // the first function sets the req argument (which was the "obj" that was passed).
    req.msg = 'Happy new year';
      // the second function calls the next argument (which was the "nxt" function passed).
    next();
  }, 
  function(req) {
     // The second function was called by the first via "nxt",
     //   and was given the same object as the first function as the first parameter,
     //   so it still has the "msg" that you set on it.
    console.log(req.msg);
  }
);
```

Note that this is a very simplified example, with fewer parameters in the functions. Not also that I changed `var` to `msg` since `var` is a reserved word.

Comment: @Patrick And what if we have more functions? Like `get([fn1, fn2, fn3, ...]);`?

Comment: @Latanmos: In that case I'd probably iterate over the `arguments` object in the `get()` function. For each argument, I'd create a new `nxt` function that calls the next function, placing each one in an Array. I'll work up an example in a minute.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you, but... Why do you use `add_fn`? Why can't I use `for() { nxt.push(...) }`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Latanmos: That's alright. It is because the `for` loop doesn't create a new scope for the variable `i`. This means that when each function that we pushed into the array finally runs (after the for loop is done), they will all be referencing the same `i` variable, which will be set at whatever the value was at the end of the loop. In other words, any code that is executed *inside* the `for` loop, will use the current value of `i`, but any code whose execution is delayed (like these functions) will be referencing the latest value of `i`. Not the `0,1,2,etc...` that you'd expect.

Comment: ...The only way to scope a variable in javascript is in a function. So we create the `add_fn` function, pass the current value of `i` to it, so that inside that function execution, we have a local variable `i` that the function being pushed into the `array` can reference. So if there were `4` functions given to `.get()`, we'll have `4` calls to `add_fn`. The first will be given the value `0`, then next `1`, then `2` and so on. Then the function that gets pushed into the array has a reference to that specific value.

Comment: ...This activity is called creating a `closure` because the function we're pushing into the Array holds a reference to a local variable that exists inside the function where it (the func we passed out) was created. In other words, the function that is now in the Array has "closed around" the local `i` variable in the `add_fn` function. It is probably a little more clear if you change the variable name inside the `add_fn` function as I did in [this updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/dWfRv/3/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want, try using the async module. It makes thing much easier to be able to run in series, parallels or use a pool.

https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Async series has been really helpful in my projects and I totally agree that this is the right way if you want control and not deal with all the parameters.